# How to use decision variable from MathematicalProgram in a multibody plant (TypeError)

Tags: drake

I'm trying to add dynamics constraints to my mathematical program. However, I get TypeError as pasted below indicating MBP is unhappy with a continuous variable being an input.

Do I need to convert the symbolic variable to numerical values somehow or is there another type of variable I should use?

Here's relevant code:

```
def add_decision_variables(prog, n_steps):
    # dimensions of x and u
    dim_x = 6
    dim_u = 2

    x = prog.NewContinuousVariables(rows=n_steps+1, cols=dim_x) # states, x[t] = [q1, q2, q3, q1_dot, q2_dot, q3_dot]
    u = prog.NewContinuousVariables(rows=n_steps+1, cols=dim_u) # input u[t] = [tau1, tau2]
    # ... other variables...

    return x, u



def add_dynamics_contstraint(prog, n_steps, decision_variables, time_step=0.0001): 
    # build plant in diagram
    builder = DiagramBuilder()
    plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=time_step)
    file_name = FindResource("models/robot.urdf")
    model = Parser(plant).AddModelFromFile(file_name)
    plant.Finalize()
    diagram = builder.Build()

    x = decision_variables[0] # states, x[t] = [q1, q2, q3, q1_dot, q2_dot, q3_dot]
    u = decision_variables[1] # [q1, q2] because q3 is not controllable

    for t in range(n_steps-1):     
        prog.AddLinearConstraint(eq(x[t,0:3] - x[t+1,0:3] - time_step*x[t+1,3::], 0))
```

Here's the error message:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
TypeError 
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-22-f2bd5b25729d> in <module>

     10 set_initial_and_goal_position(prog, decision_variables)
     11 add_contact_constraint(prog, n_steps, decision_variables)
---> 12 add_dynamics_contstraint(prog, n_steps, decision_variables)
     13 
     14 

<ipython-input-21-ff72bdc2eedf> in add_dynamics_contstraint(prog, n_steps, decision_variables, time_step)
     30 
     31         # Set plant dynamics to current state
---> 32         plant.SetPositionsAndVelocities(plant_context, x[t+1, :])
     33 
     34         # Use the plant for dynamics parameters

TypeError: SetPositionsAndVelocities(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: pydrake.multibody.plant.MultibodyPlant_[float], context: pydrake.systems.framework.Context_[float], q_v: numpy.ndarray[float64[m, 1]]) -> None
    2. (self: pydrake.multibody.plant.MultibodyPlant_[float], context: pydrake.systems.framework.Context_[float], model_instance: pydrake.multibody.tree.ModelInstanceIndex, q_v: numpy.ndarray[float64[m, 1]]) -> None

Invoked with: <pydrake.multibody.plant.MultibodyPlant_[float] object at 0x133f885b0>, <pydrake.systems.framework.LeafContext_[float] object at 0x133fa5a30>, array([Variable('x(1,0)', Continuous), Variable('x(1,1)', Continuous),
       Variable('x(1,2)', Continuous), Variable('x(1,3)', Continuous),
       Variable('x(1,4)', Continuous), Variable('x(1,5)', Continuous)],
      dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you got different answers when you posted both here and on the class discussion board, let me add one more thought.  You can add constraints in a few different ways:

```
def myconstraint(vars):
    return constraint_values

prog.AddConstraint(myconstraint, lb, ub, vars)
```

or

```
prog.AddConstraint(expression, lb, ub)
prog.AddConstraint(lb <= expression) 
...
```

The first way, if you use `def myconstraint` means you should provide a function that accepts `AutoDiffXd` (and will need `plant.ToAutoDiffXd`).  This is a more general approach, as AutoDiffXd supports more computation that we can possibly support with `symbolic::Expression`.  For example, `AutoDiffXd` works through many cases of contact in `MultibodyPlant`, but symbolic does not.

If you can obtain a symbolic version of your computation (using `plant.ToSymbolic`) then you can add the constraint as a `symbolic::Expression`.  For very big calculations, this could be slow -- and for some parts of MBP, it will be unsupported.  But one of the amazing things about this workflow, when it works, is that `MathematicalProgram` is smart enough to add linear constraints when the `symbolic::Expression` is linear (in the variables), etc.  So it can actually figure out that you have a quadratic program, and call the more specialized solver.

But based on your workflow, I suspect you will get farther faster with the `AutoDiffXd` version, like we did on the compass gait problem set.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a `plant` instantiated with symbolic variables. When you call

```
model = Parser(plant).AddModelFromFile(file_name)
```

it constructs a `plant` instantiated with python float. You could call

```
plant_symbolic = plant.ToSymbolic()
```

[ToSymbolic()](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.systems.framework.html?highlight=tosymbolic#pydrake.systems.framework.System_.System_[float].ToSymbolic) function creates a new `plant_symbolic` that accepts symbolic variables `x` and `u`.