# can we cache equations in symbolic form and plug in numbers during trajectory optimization?

Tags: drake

Is this possible to precompute the jacobians, mass matrix symbolically and only evaluate them in the optimization process?
e.g., we can cache `M = plant.CalcMassMatrixViaInverseDynamics(context)` as a symbolic matrix. When adding constraints, just write a function to plug the numeric states into the symbolic `M`.

I think in this way, we don't need to create context during constraint evaluation. Will this speed things up? Or drake is actually doing similar things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend evaluating symbolic expression in your nonlinear constraint. It is much faster to compute `M` using autodiff scalars directly. I would recommend that you create a constraint like

```
def my_constraint(plant, context, q, v):
  # Returns M[:, 0] as the constraint value.
  plant.SetPositionsAndVelocities(context, q, v)
  M = plant.CalcMassMatrixViaInverseDynamics(context)
  if q.dtype == np.object:
    # If the input type is autodiff scalars, then return M[:, 0] as a numpy array of autodiff scalars.
    return M[:, 0]
  elif q.dtype == float:
    # If the input type is float, then return M[:, 0] as a numpy array of floats.
    return pydrake.autodiffutils.autoDiffToValueMatrix(M[:,0])

prog.AddConstraint(lambda x: my_constraint(plant, context, x[:nq], x[nq:nq+nv]), lower_bound, upper_bound, vars)
```

where `plant` is a MultibodyPlant instantiate with autodiffscalar (you could call `ToAutoDiff()` to convert a `MultibodyPlant` instantiate with float or symbolic expression to one instantiate with autodiff scalar.

You could check a simple example in https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/3cae4801eac3f9cc3d948c193022ebb8bfba5124/bindings/pydrake/solvers/test/mathematicalprogram_test.py#L570-L596. This example shows how to define your own constraint evaluation function, and use it in `AddConstraint`.

Also you could refer to this stack overlow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61705629/1973861

You mentioned that

> we don't need to create context during constraint evaluation

I don't think you need to create context during constraint evaluation. In the example above, `context` is created before calling `AddConstraint` for only once. And inside `my_constraint`, `context` is updated to the current decision variable value `q` and `v`. It is never created again.